# archive page the_content returns archive post content

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I`ve created a page and selected the template for archive page.

However on the archive page, the call to `the_content` is returning the content of my archive post instead of my page. What am i doing wrong?

archive-page.php :

```
<main class="main" role="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <?php if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1><?php  echo post_type_archive_title( '', false ); ?></h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content content--aside">

                <?php
                the_archive_description();
                ?>

                    <?php
                    if (have_posts()){
                    /* Start the Loop */
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        /*
                         * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                         */
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-archive', get_post_format() );

                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    Page content: <?php the_content(); ?>
</main>
```

content-archive.php

```
<div class="medium-6 large-12 columns card-wrapper">
<a href=" <?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ) ?>" class="card">
    <div class="card__bottom card__bottom--big">
        <div class="card__bottom-group card__bottom-group--big">
            <div class="card__subtitle card__subtitle--big"><?php echo the_title() ?></div>
            <div class="card__title card__title--big">

                <?php
                if (!empty($wp_cars_description)){
                    echo substr($wp_cars_description, 0, 199).'...';
                }
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Its not clear what your problem is. The whole purpose of an archive page is to return the archived posts. Is that not what you want? If not, let us know what you *want* to happen.

Comment: What is the issue all things look like coded correctly.

Comment: @Aki  I created a page, set it template -> archive-cars, and wrote some strings, now I want echo the_content (which is description) for archive page, but Im getting nothing

Comment: @FluffyKitten see previous answer plz

Comment: Delete archive-cars.php and create page-cars.php and check.

Comment: @Aki get index page.
also, Im using archive-cars to get CPT posts, and if i write in archive-cars the_title i get the first CPT post`s title

Comment: What is the slug of cpt posts?

Comment: @Aki custom post type

Comment: I am looking for slug. What is the slug??

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You said "*Why on archive page the_content returns me a content of my archive post*" but then you say "*I want echo the_content (which is description) for archive page, but Im getting nothing*". I'm afraid I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Aki wp_cars (my template names archive-wp_cars btw)

Comment: Archives are different thing custom post type is not having templates. Create single-wp_cars.php and go to setting permalinks and click on postname and save changes.

Comment: @FluffyKitten  i guess he is trying to creat custom single.php where he can display the content of post.

Comment: @Aki See, I thought they might have been trying to create an archive page that had its own content as well as the archives for the posts themselves. Its just so unclear... its impossible to help when we don't know what they want!

Comment: @FluffyKitten  very true... let see what he said ...

Comment: @fluffykitten, yes i want to create archive page with its own content, and display this content with list of archive posts. sorry for my english and thx for helping

Comment: In that case, THere are 2 ways to do this - (1) create a standard page in WP, make this a template and apply it to your new page, or (2) create an options page (or add an option to the Theme Customizer), where the client can add content via WYSIWYG, and then output this content in the appropriate archive template. This has been answered over on wordpress.stackexchange.com here: [Adding content to archive and taxonomy pages on custom post types?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133746/adding-content-to-archive-and-taxonomy-pages-on-custom-post-types).

Comment: @fluffykitten thx for help, i saw that answer, i think the problem is the_content was not in post loop, after 3 times reading im gonna use 3rd option, ty for help, you can post this comment to answer and i check it as an answer

Comment: I'm not sure if you solved the problem, but if not: your post loop is for the archives posts, so you may need to set up a separate WP_Query for the page itself because the current query is for the archives. Let me know if you need me to expand this part of my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to create an archive page that has its own custom content as well as the archives.

There are 2 ways to do this:

**1. Create a separate page**

1. Create a standard page that will have the title and content to display on the archive
2. Make your archive-page.php above to a template, displaying the title and content from the page, and include the loop for the archives underneath. You will need to use a separate WP_Query for this and specify the CPT name, otherwise you the loop will just contain the information for the standard page.
3. Apply this template to your new page.

**2. Create an options page**

Here the custom content for the page can be added in the options page, and you can get these values using `get_option()` in archive-page.php and display them there.

More information on how to do it this way is over on wordpress.stackexchange.com here: [Adding content to archive and taxonomy pages on custom post types?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133746/adding-content-to-archive-and-taxonomy-pages-on-custom-post-types)

Comment: How do you display `the_content` of that new page and not the content of each CPT within the loop?

Comment: @DarioZadro Using `the_content` outside of your custom WP_Query loop will display the page's content. Its only inside your custom WP_Query loop that it has access to the CPT content.